# How do I report gaps with a SQL interval table?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2014

I have the following table with non-overlapping intervals and I would like to report all the possible gaps?

The table that I have:

```
Id         StartDateTime        EndDateTime

3004204 | 2014-01-01 12:47 | 2014-01-01 12:59
3004204 | 2014-01-01 13:00 | 2014-01-01 14:29
3004204 | 2014-01-01 14:30 | 2014-01-01 14:41
3004204 | 2014-01-02 18:01 | 2014-01-02 18:14
3004204 | 2014-01-02 18:15 | 2014-01-02 18:29
3004204 | 2014-01-02 18:30 | 2014-01-02 18:44
3004204 | 2014-01-02 18:45 | 2014-01-02 18:59
3004204 | 2014-01-02 19:00 | 2014-01-02 19:29
```

And what I would like is per day gap reporting per Id. So in this case it would be:

```
Id          StartDateTime       EndDateTime

3004204 | 2014-01-01 12:59 | 2014-01-01 13:00
3004204 | 2014-01-01 14:29 | 2014-01-01 14:30
3004204 | 2014-01-02 18:14 | 2014-01-02 18:15
...
```

Note: the gaps can be of arbitrary length from 1 second to 23:59 hours (currently only displaying per seconds). I think it needs to be done using lags, but that seems to rather inefficient.

Any advice whether this is even possible in SQL Server 2014 in a more efficient way than using lags and leads?

Thanks

Comment: Check out this article on the topic. https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/t-sql-programming/the-sql-of-gaps-and-islands-in-sequences/

Answer (score 2):

Find gaps per id per day using LEAD(). It's efficient and simple.

```
SELECT *
FROM
(
    SELECT  ID,
            [GapStart]  = EndDateTime,
            [GapEnd]    = LEAD(StartDateTime) OVER (PARTITION BY ID, CAST(StartDateTime AS DATE) ORDER BY StartDateTime)
    FROM @yourTable
) A
WHERE GapEnd IS NOT NULL --Filters out last row of each day
```

Comment: If reread the question again the OP says, " non-overlapping intervals" and "per day gap reporting per Id"

Comment: I feel ya. I've done the same thing more than I'd like to admit :). Thanks for the apology. It's rare that you meet people with actual character on this site.

Comment: I am very impressed, your solution seems to be amazingly short. I will test it on my data and report back :). Thank you all for helping me!

Answer (score 0):

it isn't pretty, but it should work.

```
select * from  (
    select a.Id,a.EndDate,b.StartDate
      ,row_number() over (partition by a.EndDate order by b.StartDate) as r
    from temp.test a inner join
      temp.test b on a.EndDate <= b.StartDate
    where year(a.EndDate) = year(b.StartDate)
      and month(a.EndDate) = month(b.StartDate)
      and day(a.EndDate) = day(b.StartDate)) as t
     where r = 1 and EndDate != StartDate
```

*forgot to add a final filter to eliminate when EndDate = StartDate

Comment: Why compare each part of a date, instead of comparing the whole date all in one line. Just cast each value as date. Also where in your logic do you only compare dates of the same ID?

Comment: The OP didn't mention bounding by ID, so I didn't include it. Although it would be a trivial change. You are right about the convert, although I am not sure if one mechanism is more performant than the other.

Comment: The OP says "per day gap reporting per Id". And I'm not really sure on the efficiency. My guess is about the same but better to keep it as simple as possible